# Non-Existant Ambiguous Reference Exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, blogengine.net

I am at the end of sanity.  I have been trying to incorporate the archive and post pages of blogengine.net into a different site than the actual blogging site.  Most of it works, with the exception of the post page with two controls on it that get Ambiguous Reference errors on them.

I have tried cleaning, creating different web controls, referencing under different names, changing the namespaces, changing the controls, adding new controls, but no matter what I do, I get the Ambiguous Reference.

Trying to go to the definition of the control, I am presented with two class paths, both of which resolve to the same class.  [Code Sample](http://www.ohjonny.com/images/ctb_ambiguous.png)

On the .ascx control, upon attempting to select a different web control, I see exact duplicates of the class.  [Code Sample](http://www.ohjonny.com/images/ctb_ambiguous2.png)

Everything is duplicated and I am losing my mind as to why.  I am in Visual Studio 2012, using C#.  Everything compiles clean, but the app crashes on the page that references these ambiguous controls.

Control I'm trying to use:
`<blog:SimpleCaptchaControl ID="simplecaptchaX" runat="server" TabIndex="6" />`

Also, the SimpleCaptchaControl is a class that inherits from WebControl.  I have a reference to it in the web.config that is like this:

```
<add assembly="MyStuff.Controls.Captcha" namespace="MyStuff.Controls.Captcha" tagPrefix="blog"/>
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you post your code? A screenshot of your solution and its references? The exact error?

Comment: Can you post a link to one? Feel free to add any relevant code, including the names of the classes involved.

Comment: Ok, I added links to the code images